# How to use domain instead of IP for my fullnode?

Tags: iri-node, static-ip

I set up a *full node* running Nelson, everything fine. I rented a Server together with a .de domain.

Atm I use my IP as adress of my node. Technical it works fine. But how can I change it to the domain I bought?

Comment: Create an A record on your DNS provider pointing to your IP. Then all you need to do is use the domain. http:/domain.com:port

Answer (score -1):

DNS if you don't want to pay for managed dns you can set it up locally on your server. if you're using linux with something like bind9 (https://www.vultr.com/docs/setup-your-own-dns-server-on-debian-ubuntu)

it's also worth noting to check your domain registrar because some of them have free DNS services

Comment: Really bad idea. You need two DNS Servers. Each in a different subnet and maybe other requirements may apply.